# Regular expression for allow only two or more hyphen in java?

Tags: java

Regular expression for allow only two or more hyphen in java.

Comment: Have you tried anything and please give a bit details and make sure that you have a question in your post.

Comment: which [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode) exactly?

Comment: its a perfectly clear question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sth like that:

```
String regexp = "--+";
```

And this is how to use it:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexpr);

    System.out.println(p.matcher("fsdfsa").matches()); //false
    System.out.println(p.matcher("-").matches()); //false
    System.out.println(p.matcher("--").matches()); //true
    System.out.println(p.matcher("-----").matches()); //true
```

Comment: If you only use the `matches` method, you needn't compile a Pattern manually, you can use `matches` defined in [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Comment: In the context of the example you're right. However if you intend to use a regexp more that once and it is not trivial like in this case is more efficient to precompile it once and use Pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly for the hyphen, not for a dash and not for a minus. See [Unicode Hyphen characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode).

```
String pattern = "[\u2010]{2,}";
```

you can add all of the different hyphens you want to allow into the square brackets. The following quantifier says, 2 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `\--+` will do the job.